# How to join the source data having 100 million records?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Informatica powercenter the normal join is working for src file having data 10000 records,but it's throwing error for 100 million src records.How shld I fix this issue?

I have enabled the sorted port in joiner and have even added a sorter before joiner and have sorted the ports which are same in both the sorters I have used.
I am getting the error as(no ports are sorted)

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider -

0. can you use source qualifier SQL to join in database itself? If yes, pls remove joiner and join in DB.
1. If no, can you convert the smaller tabble to a lookup ?
   If not possible, then do below steps -
2. Check if join condition is creating duplicates or not? if yes, you must use a join condition(s) which joins them on unique keys.
3. Check if you have enough space available in informatica cache directory for sorter and joiner.
   If you decide to use a sorter, pls sort the data in both pipeline based on columns used in join condition.

```
source 1 --> Sorter (order on key1,key2)----> |
                                              | --> Joiner(key1,key2)
source 2 --> Sorter (order on key1,key2)----> |
```

4. If all above fails i would say, split 100mil table into 5 chunks/files and then process one after another.

Comment: Since I am using src file not table I can't right querry in Source qualifier.. Can you suggest me how to fix this issue for src file with 10cr record in it?